# plotting/graphing excel file data using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm new to Python and there is a piece of Python coding that I am having trouble getting to graph.
Specifically how to parse data from an Excel spreadsheet in order to generate and plot some basic value comparison graphs.

I'm using the Spyder IDE with Python 3.6.3.

The file 'foc' location is: 
`C:\Users\Murphy\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\PYWorkFiles\foc.csv`
I have more than one version of the excel spreadsheet foc file as I have attempted to graph it in more than one format. The two formats it is stored in at present are `csv` and `xlsx`

The code scraps I have put together at present are:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('foc.xlsx')

from csv import reader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('foc.csv', 'r') as f:
data = list(reader(f))

taste = [i[6] for i in data]

plt.plot(range(len(taste)), taste)
plt.show()
plt.plot()
```

All these pieces of code generate is two useless graphs (I've attached them below) with only the first one even showing any of the foc spreadsheet data.

Can I get any help with this? I have very little knowledge of how to use Python.

[graph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgm66.png)

[graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHB4D.png)

Answer (score 0):

To make it as simple as possible, I recommend using numpy(`pip install numpy` to install it). Using numpy we can do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.loadtxt('foc.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and this is our [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af9Lm.png)

foc.csv:

```
1, 10
2, 20
3, 30
4, 40
5, 50
```

If you still need more help or want to get into more complex things using matplotlib, I recommend checking out sentdex's [tutorials](https://pythonprogramming.net/matplotlib-intro-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks, but that does not seem to work either.     (Part of) what I get on Spyder when I run that code is:     
  File "C:\Users\Murphy\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 725, in floatconv
    return float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'"Company\xc2\xa0'

Comment: @JAM this is because your csv file contains letters, notice how my foc.csv file is formatted. You can reformat your csv to look like mine and label the line(s) to suit your needs.